# add short description under price

Tags: hooks

Trying to build a website but seems by default it does not show the short descriptions on page.

I want to put short description below price. Tried many things but noting works really well, Just wish if anyone could help in this regards

Here is the url : https://moratofabs.com/product/cotton-60x60-fabric-block-design-anarkali-kurti-with-pant-and-dupatta-gotalace-and-heavy-adda-worked-on-yoke/

i want to put short description below product price

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `content-single-product.php` of woocommerce github, I see that product excerpt is already supposed to be after price

```php
/**
* Hook: woocommerce_single_product_summary.
*
* @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
* @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
* @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
* @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
* @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
* @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
* @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
* @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 60
*/
do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
```

So either your theme is removing this action or you are not using excerpts.

If you are not using excerpts adn you dont see theme for products, you can activate it under `screen options` tab (in the top right corner, if system language is LTR).

If you have excerpt and don't see it you will need to hook into `woocommerce_single_product_summary` at priority between 11 and 29 (maybe even between 11 and 19 if some other action was hooked into priority 20).
For example

```php
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'bt_custom_product_description', 15);
function bt_custom_product_description () {
    echo 'Some description here';
}
```